# Join the dataframe if value of one column exists as substring in another dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, substring, left-join

I have a dataframe `df1` like this:

[image]

and another dataframe `df2` like this:

[image]

How could I join `df2` with `df1` using left join so that my output would look like the following?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `split` values in `df1` and `explode` them before the join.

```py
df3 = df1.withColumn('Value', F.explode(F.split('Value', ';')))
df4 = df2.join(df3, 'Value', 'left')
```

Full example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([('apple;banana', 150), ('carrot', 20)], ['Value', 'Amount'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([('apple',), ('orange',)], ['Value'])

df3 = df1.withColumn('Value', F.explode(F.split('Value', ';')))
df4 = df2.join(df3, 'Value', 'left')

df4.show()
# +------+------+
# | Value|Amount|
# +------+------+
# | apple|   150|
# |orange|  null|
# +------+------+
```

**Dealing with nulls.** If you have nulls in the column "Value" in both dataframes which you want to successfully join, you will need to use `eqNullSafe` equality. Using this condition would normally leave "Value" columns from both dataframes in the output dataframe. So to explicitly remove it, I suggest using `alias` on dataframes.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([('apple;banana', 150), (None, 20)], ['Value', 'Amount'])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([('apple',), ('orange',), (None,)], ['Value'])

df3 = df1.withColumn('Value', F.explode(F.coalesce(F.split('Value', ';'), F.array(F.lit(None)))))
df4 = df2.alias('a').join(
    df3.alias('b'),
    df2.Value.eqNullSafe(df3.Value),
    'left'
).drop(F.col('b.Value'))

df4.show()
# +------+------+
# | Value|Amount|
# +------+------+
# | apple|   150|
# |  null|    20|
# |orange|  null|
# +------+------+
```

Comment: Hi @ZygD, thanks for the answer. It worked when the column is not null.  If the column is null, how to perform explode?

Comment: I have updated the answer with the case where you have nulls in both dataframes and you want to successfully join them. Having null in just one of the dataframes does not require that method - the first option joins well.

Answer (score 1):

Use SQL "like" operator in left outer join.
Try this

```
//Input

spark.sql(" select 'apple;banana' value,  150 amount union all  select 'carrot', 50 ").createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
spark.sql(" select 'apple' value union all  select 'orange' ").createOrReplaceTempView("df2")

//Output

spark.sql("""
select a.value, b.amount 
   from df2 a 
   left join df1 b 
   on ';'||b.value||';' like '%;'||a.value||';%' 
""").show(false)

+------+------+
|value |amount|
+------+------+
|apple |150   |
|orange|null  |
+------+------+
```